# OpenAI CLIP source code positional encoding shape not match

Tags: python, pytorch

am tracing **AttentionPool2d** source code of OpenAI CLIP at this
[github repo](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/functional.py#L5373).

This line of code confused me:

`x = x + self.positional_embedding[:, None, :].to(x.dtype)  # (HW+1)NC`

because it added a `[(NW+1),N, C]` shape tensor with a `[(spacial_dim ** 2 + 1, 1,embed_dim)]` shape tensor. I understood that `(spacial_dim ** 2 + 1) == (NW+1)` in this case , but how to explain the final dimension does not match?

```
class AttentionPool2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, spacial_dim: int, embed_dim: int, num_heads: int, output_dim: int = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.positional_embedding = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(spacial_dim ** 2 + 1, embed_dim) / embed_dim ** 0.5)
        self.k_proj = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.q_proj = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.v_proj = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.c_proj = nn.Linear(embed_dim, output_dim or embed_dim)
        self.num_heads = num_heads

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.flatten(start_dim=2).permute(2, 0, 1)  # NCHW -> (HW)NC
        x = torch.cat([x.mean(dim=0, keepdim=True), x], dim=0)  # (HW+1)NC
        x = x + self.positional_embedding[:, None, :].to(x.dtype)  # (HW+1)NC
        x, _ = F.multi_head_attention_forward(
            query=x[:1], key=x, value=x,
            embed_dim_to_check=x.shape[-1],
            num_heads=self.num_heads,
            q_proj_weight=self.q_proj.weight,
            k_proj_weight=self.k_proj.weight,
            v_proj_weight=self.v_proj.weight,
            in_proj_weight=None,
            in_proj_bias=torch.cat([self.q_proj.bias, self.k_proj.bias, self.v_proj.bias]),
            bias_k=None,
            bias_v=None,
            add_zero_attn=False,
            dropout_p=0,
            out_proj_weight=self.c_proj.weight,
            out_proj_bias=self.c_proj.bias,
            use_separate_proj_weight=True,
            training=self.training,
            need_weights=False
        )
        return x.squeeze(0)
```